# plus alphabet kind of

Tags: c, ascii

first of all, i'm a college freshman. i'd like to help my college task? i would really appreciate if you help my task.
And this task uses C language.

first i need to get two inputs (using scanf; one is alphabet like a or A and the other is arabic number like 1, 2)

and i need to add number on alphabet

ex) if i put
A 3
and the computer indicates D

here is the point, if i put Y 4 i need to get 'C' (using ASCII code and % )

the lower part is what i've tried for this task

```
int input;
char eng;

scanf("%c %d", &eng, &input);
if (eng >= 'a' && eng <= 'z') {
    eng = (eng + input) % ('z' - 'a') + eng -1;
}
```

it compiles but when i put y 4 it results x however i need c .

Comment: So that's what you've tried. What happens when you try it? Do you get a compile error? Does it compile and run but with wrong results? What were the results? Why were they wrong? It's not at all clear what you're actually asking people to do.

Comment: it was my first question and i don't know it looks like unclear .thanks for your guidance i will edit it

Answer (score 2):

You want this:

```
eng = ((eng - 'a') + input) % ('z' - 'a' + 1) +'a'
```

- `(eng - 'a')` transforms your input from `['a'..'z']` into the domain `[0..25]`.
- `+ input`  adds the offset
- `% ('z' - 'a' + 1)` does the modulo
- and finally `+ 'a'` transforms the domain `[0..25]` back into `['a'..'z']`

Comment: @genuinemango I edited the answer, the first version was wrong, try again.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. it was wrong, I corrected the answer

Comment: @jabberwocky it works !  really thanks for your teaching.